# Embed a controller within a template

Tags: symfony, twig

### We can easily embed a controller within a template in twig:

```
{% render "AcmeGolferBundle:Golfer:showGolfersList" %}
```

### When we basically use a controller like this:

```
 /**
 * Lists all golfers.
 *
 * @Route("/golfersList", name="golfers_list")
 * @Template()
 */
public function showGolfersListAction()
{
    //....doStuff
}
```

In that case, the only use of the controller will be in that template. Is there a way to avoid the user to trigger the url directly, meaning `/golferList` on its own?

### EDIT

The point I am trying to make is the following:
I need the user to use the controller through the template it is embedded in, but not directly via the url. I realise this might not be possible, but because the controller is embedded, it doesn't have a proper css structure. Therefore, if it is triggered via the url directly, it will look pretty ugly on the page.

Comment: Have you found a way to embed a widget retrieving necessary data before displaying inside the template? Or is there a way to block embedded controllers from being viewed with the direct URL? I believe that access_control will hide the controller output from regular visitors even when embedded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Securing route by IP](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#securing-by-ip) might be useful for you:

```
security: 
    # ...
    access_control:
        - { path: ^/golferList, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY, ip: 127.0.0.1 }
```

Comment: Thanks @thecatontheflat. I didn't know about this, this is very useful. However, I need the user to use the controller through the template it is embedded in, but not directly via the url. I realise this might not be possible, but because the controller is embedded, it doesn't have a proper css structure. Therefore, if it is triggers via the url directly, it will look pretty ugly on the page. I might have turned my question in a wrong way..

Comment: Do you know by any chance how to deal with a parameter like this `/{golfer_id}/golferList` ? Can we still write the path?

Comment: @Patt yes, you can use regular expressions